Getting "fully qualified" location names from a parent-child table
I have a table that contains place names, and their parent place names. Parents and children have numeric ids as well. For example:
id   name           parent_id  parent_name
---- ------         ---------- -----------
 1   Chicago         2         Cook
 2   Cook            3         Illinois
 3   Illinois        4         United States
 4   United States   NULL      NULL

What I want is to populate another field with the "fully qualified" place name. Which is to say something like this:
id   name           parent_id  parent_name      FQName  
---- ------         ---------- --------------   --------------------------------------
 1   Chicago         2         Cook             Chicago, Cook, Illinois, United States
 2   Cook            3         Illinois         Cook, Illinois, United States
 3   Illinois        4         United States    Illinois, United States
 4   United States   NULL      NULL             United States

It's recursive, so I thought of using a CTE. But since there are n levels, and n can differ depending on location (for example, the longest I'd see in a small country like Israel would be Karmiel, North, Israel), I don't know how to work it. All of the examples I've seen of CTEs go top down, because the top is known quantity (parent = NULL).
I'm sure there's something obvious that I'm missing, but I can't put my finger on it.
I'm stuck with a version of SQL Server that doesn't support STRING_AGG, so I can't use that, either.

A recursive CTE does seem to be what you want here, not STRING_AGG. Why doesn't an rCTE work exactly? What was your attempt?

STRING_AGG was added for SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later so I assume you are SQL Server 2016. Execute select @@version; to find out and let us know.

Yes, it's 2016. It's what my host is using, and they won't change it.

@ThomA, it would take me a month to go through all of the increasingly absurd things I tried. I don't know what it is about CTEs that makes my brain break down. That's one of the reasons I'm doing these. I figure if I work with enough different variants, I'll figure them out.

SQL Server 2016/2014 solution using recursive CTE
WITH CTE as (
  SELECT pn.id, 
         pn.name, 
         pn.parent_id, 
         cast(NULL as VARCHAR(512)) as ParentName,
         pn.name as FQName
  FROM placenames pn
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 FROM placenames as pn2 WHERE  pn2.id = pn.parent_id)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT b.id, 
         b.name, 
         b.parent_id, 
         a.Name as ParentName, 
         cast(b.name + ', ' + a.FQName as VARCHAR(512)) as FQName
  FROM CTE a 
  INNER JOIN placenames b ON a.id=b.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY CTE.id

fiddle



id
name
parent_id
ParentName
FQName




1
Chicago
2
Cook
Chicago, Cook, Illinois, United States


2
Cook
3
Illinois
Cook, Illinois, United States


3
Illinois
4
United States
Illinois, United States


4
United States
null
null
United States


5
Karmiel
6
North
Karmiel, North, Israel


6
North
7
Israel
North, Israel


7
Israel
null
null
Israel




A recursive CTE would be the correct general solution. However, if you know for certain that there is a maximum number of levels, you can use a series of LEFT JOINs and the CONCAT_WS() function to build your fully-qualified name.
SELECT
    P1.*,
    CONCAT_WS(', ', P1.name, P2.name, P3.name, P4.name, P5.name, P6.name) AS FQName
FROM Place P1
LEFT JOIN Place P2 ON P2.id = P1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN Place P3 ON P3.id = P2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN Place P4 ON P4.id = P3.parent_id
LEFT JOIN Place P5 ON P5.id = P4.parent_id
LEFT JOIN Place P6 ON P6.id = P5.parent_id
ORDER BY P1.id

For SQL Server versions prior to 2017 that do not support CONCAT_WS(), you can use the CONCAT() function as follows:
    CONCAT(P1.name, ', ' + P2.name, ', ' + P3.name, ', ' + P4.name,
           ', ' + P5.name, ', ' + P6.name) AS FQName

Null values will be quietly ignored.



id
name
parent_id
parent_name
FQName




1
Chicago
2
Cook
Chicago,Cook,Illinois,United States


2
Cook
3
Illinois
Cook,Illinois,United States


3
Illinois
4
United States
Illinois,United States


4
United States
null
null
United States



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
Side note: Normally, you would not store parent_name in the child row, since it is redundant with the parent row and can open up the possibilities of data inconsistencies.

@testing-for-ya - Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the answer with an alternate CONCAT() calculation.
